# What is the best way to find how long it took for a python script to finish executing without adding any extra over head?

Tags: python, performance, time

I would like to run some experiments over night and also find tomorrow morning how long it took for the experiments to finish executing. However, I would like to add as little overhead as possible so that the results from the experiments aren't affected too much by this extra timing.

I read from various resources that `time script.py` would be a good way to measure that. However I am not sure how `time` works and how much it can affect my experiments.

Comment: open ur terminal and execute `man time`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ought to be pretty minimal overhead, and simple to implement

```
import time

t1 = time.time()

# code goes here

print('Took {} seconds'.format(time.time() - t1))
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, `time` Linux command simply asks kernel to provide information on the process that was run using it. Since kernel collects CPU and other information for all processes anyway, running `time` with a script doesn't impact the performance of the script itself (or its negligible)

The above answer is correct but it may not be idempotent. A script time can be affected due to current load, data size it is processing, network and so on.

I recommend using the Linux `time` command since it provides lot more information about the process. You can then run it under different loads and compare them.